# How do I create a comoving quantity using YT?

Tags: cosmology, units

I can assign a unit to a scalar using:
x = YTQuantity(scalar, 'kpc')

but how would I specify that the unit should be kpccm? Perhaps it doesn't even make sense to do so? Something as simple as this is not the answer:
x = YTQuantity(scalar, 'kpccm')

Thank you,
Paul

Comment: Your question clearly is about programming, but definitely misses some context. Most notably the language and the package(s) you are working with. Also: What unit is kpccm? It's not anything self-explanatory to me

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://yt-project.org/doc/analyzing/units.html#comoving-units-for-cosmological-simulations), it seems to me that it _is_ in fact as simple as appending 'cm' to a length unit.

Comment: @planetmaker "yt" is a very astro-specific Python package for analyzing 3D data, and the "cm" should be the specificer for **c**o**m**oving units